# How to export Azure Analytics data

Tags: azure, visual-studio-app-center

I am using AppCenter to get analytics data. This data can be visualized in Azure Metrics - AppInsights (ie: Funnels, User Flows... etc). I was wondering if there is a solution to export all this data to single or multiple files.

I read the Azure documentation but I couldn't find anything concrete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export this data to blob storage or AppInsights . If you go to **`Settings -> Export`** you will be able to see the options to export to.

[image]

Then you could go through the storage account inorder to download the files.

Comment: And how to access the Blob Storage data and can we download those files?